# After deleting item, RecyclerView does not update

Tags: android, realm, android-recyclerview

I'm implementing a RecyclerView to show a list of Transactions. In one of its two ViewHolders, there is a button to delete transaction. The problem is, after clicking the button, nothing happened to the RecyclerView. I'm using Realm and MVP pattern, and have tried all solutions I could find, but nothing seems to work.

Here's TransactionListActivity, where the RecyclerView will be shown:

```
public class TransactionListActivity extends BaseActivity implements TransactionListView {

private static final String TAG = "TransactionListActivity";

@Inject
TransactionListPresenterInterface<TransactionListView> mPresenter;

TransactionListAdapter transactionListAdapter;

@BindView(R.id.transaction_list_recyclerview)
RecyclerView transactionListRecyclerView;

@Override
public void onPrepareTransactionListAdapter() {
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
            = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

    transactionListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    List<TransactionListItem> transactionListItems = mPresenter.getAllTransactionItems();

    transactionListAdapter = new TransactionListAdapter(this, transactionListItems);
    transactionListAdapter.setOnDeleteTransactionClickListener(this::onDeleteTransaction);

    transactionListRecyclerView.setAdapter(transactionListAdapter);

}

@Override
public void onDeleteTransaction(String id) {
    mPresenter.onDeleteTransactionClick(String id);
}

@Override
public void refresh() {
    transactionListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_transaction_list);

    getActivityComponent().inject(this);

    setUnBinder(ButterKnife.bind(this));
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    mPresenter.onAttach(this);

    onPrepareTransactionListAdapter();
}
```

Here's my adapter:

```
public class TransactionListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = "TransactionListAdapter";

private Context context;
public List<TransactionListItem> transactionListItems;
private OnDeleteTransactionClickListener mOnDeleteTransactionClickListener;

public TransactionListAdapter(Context context, List<TransactionListItem> transactionListItems) {
    this.context = context;
    this.transactionListItems = transactionListItems;
}

class TransactionItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ...

    @BindView(R.id.delete_transaction_button)
    Button deleteTransactionButton;

    ...

    public TransactionItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}

class TransactionDateViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ...
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

    switch(viewType) {

        case TransactionListItem.TYPE_DATE:
            //inflate TransactionDateViewHolder here

        case TransactionListItem.TYPE_TRANSACTION:
            //inflate TransactionItemViewHolder here
    }

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    switch(viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {

        case TransactionListItem.TYPE_TRANSACTION:

            ProductStockRecord productStockRecord = (ProductStockRecord) transactionListItems.get(position);
            TransactionItemViewHolder transactionItemViewHolder = (TransactionItemViewHolder) viewHolder;
            // populate view with data here
            ((TransactionItemViewHolder) viewHolder).deleteTransactionButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                if (mOnDeleteTransactionClickListener != null) {
                    mOnDeleteTransactionClickListener.onDeleteTransactionClick(productStockRecord.getId());
                }
            });
            break;

        case TransactionListItem.TYPE_DATE:

            //populate view with data here
            break;

    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return transactionListItems.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) { return transactionListItems.get(position).getType(); }

public void setOnDeleteTransactionClickListener(final OnDeleteTransactionClickListener onDeleteTransactionClickListener) {
    mOnDeleteTransactionClickListener = onDeleteTransactionClickListener;
}

public interface OnDeleteTransactionClickListener {
    void onDeleteTransactionClick(String id);
}
```

}

And here's my presenter:

```
public class TransactionListPresenter<V extends TransactionListView> extends BasePresenter<V> implements TransactionListPresenterInterface<V>, RealmDataManager.OnTransactionCallback {

private static final String TAG = "TransaxListPresenter";

@Inject
public TransactionListPresenter(final RealmDataManager realmDataManager) { super(realmDataManager); }

@Override
public List<TransactionListItem> getAllTransactionItems() {
    List<ProductStockRecord> productStockRecordList = getRealmDataManager().getAllProductStockRecords();

    List<TransactionListItem> transactionListItems = new ArrayList<>();
    // preprocess transactions here

    return transactionListItems;
}

@Override
public void onDeleteTransactionClick(String id) {
    getRealmDataManager().deleteProductStockRecord(id, this);
    getView().refresh();
    Log.d(TAG,"deleteTransaction() performed");
}
```

}

Here's the updated (and working) version of RealmService, and all codes above have been fixed accordingly:

```
public void deleteProductStockRecord(final String id, final OnTransactionCallback onTransactionCallback) {
    mRealm.executeTransactionAsync(realm -> {
        ProductStockRecord productStockRecord = realm.where(ProductStockRecord.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
        productStockRecord.deleteFromRealm();
    }, () -> {
        if (onTransactionCallback != null) {
            onTransactionCallback.onRealmSuccess();
        }
    }, error -> {
        if (onTransactionCallback != null) {
            onTransactionCallback.onRealmError(error);
        }
    });
}
```

I believe I make some mistakes somewhere in my adapter implementation. I would be really thankful if anyone could help me fix the problem, point my mistake, or point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance

Comment: Because you map everything to `ArrayList` and don't listen for writes to realm, and you probably don't re-read the data in your custom `onRealmSuccess()` callback

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I don't quite understand. Could you please elaborate more or give some examples?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the official example? https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/ad88afe897a9fe6ca6f00fb04586e78f06b1b539/examples/gridViewExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmgridview/GridViewExampleActivity.java#L34-L66

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I did look here: [realm-android-adapters](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/tree/master/adapters/src/main/java/io/realm) [android-mvp-material-and-realm](https://github.com/NileshJarad/android-mvp-material-and-realm/tree/master/MyApplication/android-mvp-material-and-realm-master/src/main/java/com/nileshjarad/realmdemo/views) [example-realm-mvp-dagger](https://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/android/example-realm-mvp-dagger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue might be the reference to `List<TransactionListItem>` is not updated in your adapter.

If you look at this code in your presenter:

```
@Override
public List<TransactionListItem> getAllTransactionItems() {
    List<ProductStockRecord> productStockRecordList = getRealmDataManager().getAllProductStockRecords();

    List<TransactionListItem> transactionListItems = new ArrayList<>();
    // preprocess transactions here

    return transactionListItems;
}
```

You're creating a new `List<TransactionListItem>` which is what your adapter is pointing to. So in your `onDeleteTransactionClick` method, you have to make sure you pass the updated list to your adapter before calling `getView().refresh()`. Because otherwise, the list in the adapter won't change and you will see that the item is not being deleted.

Ideally though, I would recommend using something like `DiffUtil` (or calculate manually) to get the position of the deleted item and call `notifyItemRemoved` instead of refreshing the entire `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you meant "recyclerview visibly does not change":

If you delete an item from a recyclerview, you can use `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. Doing this updates the contents of the visible recyclerview to the items in the list of the adapter at the moment of calling.